# Удаление определённой записи по номеру в файле

Tags: c++, c, структуры, запись

Задача: удалить определённую запись структуры по номеру, который введёт юзер.

Вот,что я сам попробовал сделать:

```
void udalenie()
{
    int i, s;
    vivod();
    printf("\nNomer mashini,kotoruiu udaleaem: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &i);
    fopen_s(&f, "car.dat", "r");
    fopen_s(&nov, "nov.dat", "wb+");
    s = 0;
    while (fread(&car1, sizeof(car1), 1, f) != NULL)
    {
        s++;
        if (s != i)
        {
            fwrite(&car1, sizeof(car1), 1, nov);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    fclose(nov);
}
```

Не работает,как надо. У меня 3 записи. 0,1,2.
КАК РАБОТАЕТ:
Ввожу 0 - ничего не меняется
Ввожу 1 - удаляется 0
Ввожу 2 - удаляется 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте приращивать s в конце цикла while.

```
s = 0;
while (fread(&car1, sizeof(car1), 1, f) != NULL)
{
    if (s != i)
    {
        fwrite(&car1, sizeof(car1), 1, nov);
    }
    s++;
}
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ВАМ ОГРОМНОЕ!!!!

Comment: Ошибку-то свою поняли? вводите индекс с нуля, а считали с единицы.

Comment: Понял уже,глупые вообще ошибки совершал,пока писал лабораторную эту... За то много опыта.